# How to return response code 400 instead of stack trace or ignoring json attribute?

Tags: java, json, spring, http, jackson

When I send unsupported JSON request I receive stack trace from Jackson that it doesn't have this property. On the @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) I just got a response without necessary obtaining as expected.
But how can I return for example 400 or another response code without stack trace?

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "dave" (Class com.atlassian.troubleshooting.jfr.domain.JfrSettings), not marked as ignorable
 at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@8aaf377; line: 1, column: 14] (through reference chain: com.atlassian.troubleshooting.jfr.domain.JfrSettings["dave"])
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializationContext.unknownFieldException(StdDeserializationContext.java:267)
```

Answer (score 0):

For me `HttpMessageNotReadableException` is thrown and `UnrecognizedPropertyException` is the nested exception. you can use `SimpleMappingExceptionResolver` and configure it like:

```
@Configuration
public class CustomConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Bean
    public SimpleMappingExceptionResolver simpleMappingExceptionResolver(){
        var mappings = new Properties();
        mappings.setProperty("HttpMessageNotReadableException", "errorpage");
        var statusCode = new Properties();
        statusCode.setProperty("errorpage", String.valueOf(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST));
        var exeptionResolver = new SimpleMappingExceptionResolver();
        exeptionResolver.setStatusCodes(statusCode);
        exeptionResolver.setExceptionMappings(mappings);
        return exeptionResolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureHandlerExceptionResolvers(
            List<HandlerExceptionResolver> resolvers) {
        resolvers.add(simpleMappingExceptionResolver());
    }
}
```

or use `@ControllerAdvice` like:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ControllerAdvisor {

    @ExceptionHandler(HttpMessageNotReadableException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleCityNotFoundException(
            HttpMessageNotReadableException ex, WebRequest request) {
        // do stuff with ex and request
        return new ResponseEntity<>("body", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

}
```

also as I said in the beginning the exception is `HttpMessageNotReadableException` and `UnrecognizedPropertyException` is just nested inside `HttpMessageNotReadableException`. If you use `UnrecognizedPropertyException` in above codes it won't work.